# Azure Function ImportError FunctionRegister when runnning on cloud

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a durable app function running on versions 3.x written in pyhton 3.7 that worked fine from the last 1 year. After a new release due to a minor change in software I had to redeploy the function app via

```
func azure functionapp publish
```

When I try to run it locally using the Debug tool in VS Code I don't get any error and everything works fine, but now when I run it in cloud (in az portal for instance) i get this error:

> Result: Failure Exception: ImportError: cannot import name 'FunctionRegister' from 'azure.functions' (/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure/functions/**init**.py). Troubleshooting Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 318, in _handle__function_load_request func_request.metadata.entry_point) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 42, in call raise extend_exception_message(e, message) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 40, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.7/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 85, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import File "", line 983, in _find_and_load File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked File "", line 728, in exec_module File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/home/site/wwwroot/ClientStarter/**init**.py", line 5, in  import azure.durable_functions as df File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/durable_functions/**init**.py", line 14, in  from .decorators import DFApp File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/durable_functions/decorators/**init**.py", line 4, in  from .durable_app import DFApp File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/durable_functions/decorators/durable_app.py", line 10, in  from azure.functions import FunctionRegister, TriggerApi, BindingApi, AuthLevel

I understood that there are some problems with module due to pyhton version and app version but I cannot go with 4.x, is there a way to still use 3.x and avoid the error?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest short term solution is fix the version in your requirement.txt to version 1.1.6

```
... #other requirements
azure-functions-durable==1.1.6
...
```

Comment: This solution definitely works! The problem was in the last version of that azure-functions-durable library. Now using app version 3.x and python 3.7 the error is not appearing anymore. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact issue today - upgrading python to 3.9 AND upgrading the azure function to runtime version ~4 cured the issue.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks. How can I do it? I deploy the functionapp via 'func azure functionapp publish' so it's just doing everything alone. How can I specify pyhton version? Do you think it's taking my pyhton version from local machine (that in fact is exactly 3.7.9) ?

Comment: Hi - sorry I did two things and it turned out to be both - I've updated my answer. Try updating the function runtime version in the portal to be ~4.

Comment: ok same for me updating just version to ~4. I'm looking for smt for ~3 version..

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Function Apps with runtime stack as `Python`is limited to `Python 3.9`.

Before executing durable functions in visual studio code, I got the same kind of warning as below:

[image]

It states that it supports up to `Python 3.10` versions for executing `durable orchestrator` functions in visual Studio Code, but not the most recent ones. (Python 3.11)

**Note**: When working with Durable functions, version compatibility must be checked (Python). Otherwise, it will throw an "***import errors***".

After meeting all of the prerequisites, I tried creating and executing the sample orchestrator, activity as well as client functions in my environment by installing dependencies and it worked successfully.

***Orchestrator***-> `init.py`:

```py
import  logging
import  json
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  azure.durable_functions  as  df
def  orchestrator_function(context: df.DurableOrchestrationContext):
result1 = yield  context.call_activity('Hello', "Tokyo")
result2 = yield  context.call_activity('Hello', "Seattle")
result3 = yield  context.call_activity('Hello', "London")
return [result1, result2, result3]
main = df.Orchestrator.create(orchestrator_function)
```

***requirements.txt:***

```py
azure-functions
azure-functions-durable
```

***DurableHttpStarter function*** -> `init.py`:

```py
import  logging
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  azure.durable_functions  as  df
async  def  main(req: func.HttpRequest, starter: str) -> func.HttpResponse:
client = df.DurableOrchestrationClient(starter)
instance_id = await  client.start_new(req.route_params["functionName"], None, None)
logging.info(f"Started orchestration with ID = '{instance_id}'.")
return  client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Triggered*** [localhost:7071/api/orchestrators/FunctionName]:

[image]

***Check runtime  status*** [localhost:7071/api/orchestrators/StatusQueryGetUri]:

[image]

***Deployment successful:***

[image]

[image]

***Published to function app in portal:***

[image]

***Updated:***

[image]

Reference: [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode?tabs=windows)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation but I'm able to deploy function app on portal like you but when I run it I get the error above. So the problem is on the run..when the function is executed

Comment: When I run the function after deploying also, it gave me 202 response without any error. I will update it if needed.

Comment: @SalvatoreNedia Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: In my case I have python version 3.7.9 and app function versions 3.x and i still get 500 with the error (described above) on cloud. Are u saying that is something due to python version?

Comment: Yes 3.10 version is supporting.